# Hinkommen - Sprachgebrauch

Tags: grammar, translation

Ich habe oftmals *wie kommt man da hin?* gehört. Darf man *da* durch einen bestimmen Ort (in Verbindung mit irgendeiner passenden Präposition) ersetzen? Es ist mir auch aufgefallen, dass die

> *wie kommt man nach _____?*

Konstruktion häufig benutzt wird.
Ich will grundsätzlich

> *How does one go to _____ / How does one get there?*

ins Deutsche übersetzen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nein, du darfst in »Wie kommt man da hin?« das Wort »da« nicht durch einen Ort (mit oder ohne Präposition) ersetzen. Wenn doch, musst du auch das »hin« weglassen.

Vergleiche:

> 1. Ich will nach Wien. Wie komme ich da hin?
> 2. Wie komme ich nach Wien? Ich will da hin.

In Englisch wäre das:

> 1. I want to go to Vienna. How do I get there?
> 2. How do I get to Vienna? I want to go there.

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienne_%28Is%C3%A8re%29

Comment: Kleine Anmerkung: "Wie komme ich da hin?" würde (zumindest in Ö) besser "Wie komme ich dort hin" formuliert.

Comment: @guntbert: Richtig. In Österreich wird recht streng zwischen »da« und »dort« unterschieden. »Da« ist immer dort wo sich der Sprecher gerade befindet. »Dort« ist ein Ort, an dem sich der Sprecher nicht befindet. In Deutschland verwendet man beide Wörter beinahe synonym.

Answer (score 2):

Das standardsprachlich korrekte Richtungsadverb schreibt man als ein Wort *([dahin](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dahin) gehen* und nicht *da hin gehen)*, unabhängig davon, ob es normal [[daˈhɪn]](http://www.duden.de/_media_/audio/ID4107922_494172970.mp3) oder hinweisend mit besonderem Nachdruck [[ˈdaːhɪn]](http://www.duden.de/_media_/audio/ID4157189_96307863.mp3) betont wird.

> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder dahin fahren
>
> wie soll ich ohne Auto dahin kommen?
>
> wir können zu Fuß dahin gehen
>
> wie weit ist es bis dahin?

Die Konstruktionen mit dem Lageadverb *(da hingehen)* sind laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* regional- oder umgangssprachlich:

> Im Engadin ist es schön. Da solltet ihr auch einmal hinfahren.
>
> Das ist eine nette Bar. Da werde ich öfter einmal hingehen.

Das Richtungsadverb *dahin* kann durch „an diesen Ort“ oder durch eine andere Konstruktion mit einer räumlichen Präposition zur Angabe der Richtung ersetzt werden:

> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder *dahin* fahren
> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder *an diesen Ort* fahren
> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder *an die Nordsee* fahren
> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder *nach Hamburg* fahren
> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder *auf die Zugspitze* fahren
> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder *in die Berge* fahren
> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder *durch die Stadt* fahren
> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder *um die Ecke* fahren
> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder *aus der Garage* fahren
> wir wollen nächstes Jahr wieder *gegen die Wand* fahren