# "dahin" vs. "da hin"

Tags: grammar, difference, meaning

Ich habe schon mal im Internet nachgeguckt, aber mir ist immer noch etwas unklar, worin genau der Unterschied dazwischen liegt, also grammatikmäßig.
Es kommt mir irgendwie vor, dass es davon abhängt, was man eigentlich ausdrücken möchte. Aber es könnte ja sein, dass ich mich völlig irre.

Comment: siehe auch meine Antwort zu deiner Frage [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18575/hinkommen-sprachgebrauch/18578#18578)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Von ein paar Ausnahmen und Ellipsen abgesehen sind "hin" und "her" entweder Teil eines Präpositionaladverbs oder eines Verbs. In beiden Fällen haben sie die gleiche Funktion. Ist ein Verb im Satz, so gehören sie standardmäßig **zum Verb**.

Ist auch ein "da" im Satz, ergibt sich daraus im Präsens automatisch "... da hin" am Ende. Als erstes Beispiel nehme ich "hinsetzen" aus Glorias Antwort:

> Setz dich da hin!
>   Setz dich dahin.

**Beides ist völlig richtig.**
Im ersten Satz ist das Verb "hinsetzen", im zweiten "setzen". 
Es gibt anscheinend einige, die das nicht wahrhaben wollen, weil Duden. Hier also die Begründung

Erstens kann man das "da" weglassen und sagen:

> Setz dich hin!

Ein klares Indiz, dass "hinsetzen" existiert. Da brauche ich nichtmal für in den Duden gucken (Gott sei Dank). 
Ein weiteres Beispiel mit einem anderen Verb:

> ..., dass ich das da hingestellt habe.
>   ..., dass ich das dahin gestellt habe.

Beide existieren. Beide werden **unterschiedlich** betont und zwischen beiden besteht ein leichter Bedeutungsunterschied. Die zweite Version ist extrem "markiert" und stellt "stellen" in einen Kontrast zu zum Beispiel schmeißen. Die erste Version ist die natürlichere, was auch Sinn macht. "Da" ist eine Ortskonstituente, "hin" markiert das "stellen" und gibt ihm eine Richtung. Andere Optionen wären "reinstellen", "rausstellen", "raufstellen". Da würde auch niemand - nichtmal der Duden - argumentieren, dass es hochsprachlich

> ..., dass ich das darauf gestellt habe.

heißen müsste.

PS: evtl. Downvotes bitte begründen und Gegenargumente bringen.

Comment: *Dahinstellen* bedeutet sogar etwas ganz anderes als *da hinstellen*.

Answer (score 5):

Dies scheint ein sehr gängiges Problem zu sein und es gab in letzter Zeit einige Fragen, die das Problem aufgeworfen habe, vor allen Dingen in Kombination mit konkreten Verben, zum Beispiel "wohin fliegen vs wo hinfliegen".

Ich habe dazu im Blog von canoo.net den Artikel [Irgendwohin gehen oder irgendwo hingehen](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2013/09/25/irgendwohin-gehen-oder-irgendwo-hingehen/) gefunden.

Dort heißt es:

> in „einwandfreiem“ Standarddeutsch schreiben Sie:
>
> > irgendwohin gehen

Weiter heißt es aber:

> Die Richtungsadverbien woher und wohin werden allerdings in der gesprochenen Alltagssprache häufig durch die getrennte Variante wo … her und wo … hin ersetzt:
>
> > Woher kommst du? – Wo kommst du her?
> >     Wohin gehst du? – Wo gehst du hin?

Um deine Frage zu beantworten:

- Einen Unterschied gibt es nicht.
- Die Verwendung von *dahin* ist richtig(er).
- Die Trennung von *da* und *hin* ist umgangssprachlich gängig.

Comment: dahin != da hin

Comment: @Grantwalzer Und der wäre?

Comment: Die Verwendung iSv *fort* bzw. *vergangen* etc. führt zu uneindeutigen Aussagen wie "Ich gehe dahin".

Comment: @Grantwalzer Auch wenn ich nur die Hälfte von deinem Kommentar verstehe, beziehst du dich mit "Ich gehe dahin" auf eine ganz andere Bedeutung von "dahingehen", die überhaupt gar nicht Bestandteil der Frage ist.

Comment: Gerade aufgrund dieser möglichen Bedeutung reicht es nicht, nur den allgemeinen Unterschied zwischen Umgangs- und Standardsprache anzuführen.

Comment: Gilt diese Erklärung explizit nur für "gehen"? Wenn nicht, dann bitte erklären, warum die Zeitungen mit "dort hingestellt" kein Problem zu haben scheinen. Könnte es sein, dass die Umgangssprachigkeit eher von "da" an sich kommt? Fakt ist, dass, wenn ein Lerner nach dem Lesen dieser Antwort prinzipiell das Adverb benutzt, dann wird er unidiomatisch schreiben und reden und evtl. sogar etwas anderes ausdrücken als gedacht.

Comment: Man kann auch mal ein Verschiebeprobe machen "Hingegangen ist er da." hat einen leicht anderen Fokus als "Gegangen ist er dahin". Und hier empfinde ich das erste als deutlich weniger konstruiert. Ein weiteres Indiz, dass das "hin" ans Verb gehört, egal was die üblichen Verdächtigen sagen.

Comment: @Emanuel Nun gut, aber deine Sätze sagen hier tatsächlich was ganz anderes aus. "Hingegangen ist er da, zurückgegangen ist dort" vs "Gegangen ist er dahin, geflogen ist er dorthin" – Und jetzt machen wir wieder nen deutschen Satz draus: "Er ist dahin gegangen" == "Er ist da hingegangen"

Comment: @Em1... ja, stimmt. So kann man mein Beispiel auch lesen. Ich meinte aber "da" im Sinne von "zu diesem Ort", nicht "auf diesem Weg"... so wie in "Gehört habe ich davon schon aber hingegangen bin ich da nie." Versteh mich nicht falsch, deine Antwort hat eine Quelle und ist okay. Ich denke nur einfach, dass die Quellen in diesem Fall nicht so wirklich verstanden haben, worüber sie reden. Ich habe mich ein bisschen bei den Zeitungen umgeschaut und Formulierungen mit "dort/dahin  ge.." überwiegen den Gegenpart mit "dort/ da hinge." etwa zwei zu eins. Ich finde "umgangsprachlich" einfach zu stark

Comment: ... so als wäre das schlechter Stil. Es ist auf jeden Fall standardsprachlich, wenn auch vielleicht nicht hochsprachlich (obgleich ich auch im Feuilleton Beispiele gefunden habe). Und neben der Realität ist eben noch die Tatsache, dass die Regel keinen Sinn macht und bei anderen, ähnlichen Fällen nicht greift.

Answer (score 3):

Mit der Formulierung "da hin" wird ausschließlich eine Richtung oder Ortsangabe bezeichnet.

> Die Sitzordnung ist sehr strikt. Setz dich *da* hin! 
>  Auf mein Zeichen wechseln wir die Plätze: Du kommst hier hin, wo ich jetzt stehe, und ich gehe da hin, wo du jetzt stehst.

"Dahin" wird manchmal in dem gleichen Zusammenhang verwendet. Es gibt auch kombinierte Fälle wie "dahingehend", das wahrscheinlich einfach aus "dahin gehend" zusammengezogen wurde.

Vom Sinn her würde ich "dahin" als Synonym zu "verloren", "verflossen", "vergangen" verwenden. Genau genommen würde man die zwei Varianten auch in der Aussprache unterscheiden können:

> Jetzt setz dich doch mal *da* hin! 
>  O Jammer! Da*hin* ist alle Hoffnung!

Da würde ich mich aber nicht drauf verlassen ;)

Edit:
Gut, mein letztes Beispiel ist vielleicht nicht das beste. *Dahin* und *hierhin* gibt es auch. Die werden in genau dem gleichen Sinne verwendet wie *da hin* und *hier hin*. Sie sind vielleicht sogar die korrektere Form. Semantisch besteht zwischen diesen zwei Varianten ein minimaler Unterschied, da meiner Meinung nach *dahin* nicht ohne einen Relativsatz stehen kann. Die Formulierung wäre also

> dahin, wo [du stehst/die Musik spielt/…]

im Gegensatz zu *hin*, das hier in einer ähnlichen Bedeutung wie das häufiger verwendete *weg* verstanden werden muss. (Sorry, dafür fehlt mir gerade einfach der Fachbegriff^^) Ich würde sagen, es ist verkürzt von *zu etwas hin*. In Verbindung mit dem *da* ist es allerdings umgangssprachlich, das *da* unterstreicht dann lediglich die Tatsache, dass es nicht der eigene, momentane Standort ist.

> Ich gehe jetzt da [zu den Musikern] hin.

In der gesprochenen Sprache macht es zum Glück gar keinen Unterschied, und die Schwelle zur Haarspalterei scheint mir hier niedrig zu sein. ;)

Comment: „da hin“ und „hier hin“ sind falsch. Richtig sind die Adverbien [_dahin_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dahin#Bedeutung1) bzw. [_hierhin_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hierhin)

Comment: Man kann aber auch "hin" ohne alles verwenden. "Ich hab keine Lust mehr von weitem zuzuschauen, ich gehe jetzt hin." --> "Ich gehe da jetzt hin." --> "Ich gehe da hin."

Comment: @Loong Wie wäre es denn mit "ich will auch hin".
In diesem Fall, wird "gehen" ausgelassen? Also ich meine,eine Abkürzung für hingehen?

Comment: @neutronhammer Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hin#Bedeutung6) ist dieser spezielle Fall, also das meist elliptisch gebrauchte, allein stehende _hin_ („ich will hin“, „nichts wie hin“) umgangssprachlich.

Comment: @Loong Die getrennte Schreibweise gibt es allemal: *hinsetzen - Ich setze mich hin - Ich setze mich da hin*.

Comment: @Gloria Laut Duden ist die Konstruktion mit dem Lageadverb _da_ + _hingehen_ („Ich gehe da jetzt hin.“) regions- oder umgangssprachlich für die standardsprachlich korrekte und von der Dudenredaktion empfohlene Konstruktion mit dem Richtungsadverb _dahin_ + _gehen_ „Ich gehe jetzt dahin.“

Comment: @Loong... der Duden kann viel empfehlen. Es ist nur ein Buch. Davon abgesehen ist die Empfehlung wenn dann nur für diesen Fall gültig. Siehe meine Antwort fr mehr Details

Comment: "[dahingehend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dahin_gehend)" (oder "dahin gehend") hat aber in erster Linie eine andere Bedeutung als "zu einer gezeigten Stelle gehen". – Und "dahin" hat noch einen zeitlichen Aspekt. Bisher ganz untergegangen anscheinend.

Comment: @Em1 Das stimmt. Ich bin aber davon ausgegangen, dass hier nur der Unterschied in der Schreibweise gemeint ist, wenn die Formulierung in demselben Sinnzusammenhang gebraucht werden soll.

Comment: @Gloria Mein Downvote und mein erster Kommentar bezogen sich eigentlich nur auf deine Vermutung, dass _dahin gehen_ ein Rechtschreibfehler sei. Da du diesen Punkt mittlerweile korrigiert hast, habe ich den Downvote wieder zurückgenommen.

Comment: Ja, das war irgendwie ein fehlgeleiteter Gedanke meinerseits. Ich wollte eher ausdrücken, was @Emanuel oben schreibt, nämlich den Unterschied zwischen "gehen" und "hingehen". Aber da hängte ich mich an dem "da" auf und von da an ging's bergab ;)