# “dahin” vs. “hin”

Tags: grammar, difference, meaning

Zwar weiß ich, dass ein ähnliches Thema schon existiert:
["dahin" vs. "da hin"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18640/dahin-vs-da-hin)

aber, ich möchte etwas anderes fragen:

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen “dahin” und “hin”:

Im Raum (Da) steht ein Stuhl,

1. du kannst dich dahin setzen (da hinsetzen).
2. du kannst dich hinsetzen.
3. du kannst dich setzen.

Soweit ich weiß, der 1. ist immer mit irgendeinem Kontext verbunden, aber der 2. manchmal auch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Frage lautet nicht wirklich, was der Unterschied zwischen *dahin* und *hin* ist. Vielmehr ist der Unterschied zwischen *da setzen*, *dahin setzen*, *da hinsetzen* und *dahin hinsetzen* gesucht. Dies sind alle Kombinationen die aus den beiden Verben *setzen* und *hinsetzen* sowie den beiden Adverbien *da* und *dahin* gebildet werden können.

Im ersten Satz setzt man sich, und zwar genau dorthin, wo jemand grade mit seinem Finger hinzeigt.

Im zweiten und dritten Satz setzt man sich einfach (hin), und zwar theoretisch, wo(hin) immer einem beliebt. In der Regel ist der Sitzplatz aber aus der Situation ableitbar. Es gibt hier keinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Verben.

Beispiel: Wenn der Doktor sagt, dass ich mich *(hin)setzen* kann, meint er damit in der Regel den Stuhl ihm gegenüber (oder ggf. die Liege).
Wenn nun aber in dem Raum viele Stühle stehen und ich mich auf einen bestimmten Stuhl setzen soll, wird er auf den Stuhl zeigen und mir sagen, dass ich mich eben *dahin setzen* soll (oder *da hinsetzen* oder *dahin hinsetzen*).

Also mit *da* bzw. *dahin* wird Bezug auf den Sitzplatz genommen.
Mit *setzen* bzw. *hinsetzen* wird auf die Aktion Bezug genommen.

Comment: Könntest du noch was zu "setzen" vs "hinsetzen" ergänzen?

Comment: Ist "dahin hinsetzen" auch korrekt? (also 2 mal "hin")

Comment: @Em1
Vielmehr ist der Unterschied zwischen da setzen, dahin setzen, da hinsetzen und dahin hinsetzen gesucht.

Eigentlich schon, das Verb kann aber anderes sein:
schauen, gehen, usw...

Comment: @Emanuel Auf was genau nimmst du jetzt Bezug?

Comment: @Deni Es ist quasi doppelt gemoppelt, aber nichts dagegen einzuwenden. – Scheuen? Du meinst schauen? Ja, das Verb is relativ egal. Stimmt, aber "hin-" gehört zum Verb.

Comment: @Deni Richtig ist es theoretisch schon, aber ich glaube nicht, dass jemand tatsächlich "Setzen Sie sich dahin hin." oder "Ich setzte mich dahin hin." sagen würde.

Comment: Nach dem Motto das eins deutlicher formaler ist. Das ist öfter so, mit diesen "behinbaren" Verben.

Comment: @Emanuel Hm, ich denke, da muss ich passen, weil ich diesbzgl. nicht wirklich einen Unterschied sehe.