# Hin/her-Verben und ihre Grundverben

Tags: verb, preposition, verb-usage, separable-verb

Ich finde es besonders schwierig, den Unterschied zwischen dem Grundverb und dem einschlägigen 'hin/her-' Verb zu begreifen, und deshalb wäre es für mich super, wenn ihr mir helfen könntet! :)

Ich würde aber die Grundbedeutung von 'hin/her-' vernachlässigen:ich weiß ja, dass der Unterschied zwischen bringen/hinbringen/herbringen darin liegt, dass man in den letzten zwei Fällen die Bewegungsrichtung aus der Sicht des Sprechers unterstreicht. Was mich verwirrt, ist was leicht Anderes.

Zum Beispiel: hin/her-werfen/werfen und hingehen/gehen.
In Bezug auf den ersten Fall würde ich sagen, dass - wenn die Richtung nicht angegeben wird - man etw. 'hinwirft'. Ist es doch denn wirklich so?
Kann ich nur sagen 'Ich habe den Stein hin/her-geworfen' oder geht auch 'Ich habe den Stein (keine Richtungsangabe) geworfen'? Und - außer ich will hervorbringen, dass der Stein von mir weg hingeworfen oder zu mir hergeworfen wurde - würde ich also nur sagen sollen 'er hat den Stein in den Teich geworfen'?

Was hingehen angeht, frage ich mich, zum einen, ob es auch hier gilt, dass man ohne Richtung 'hingehen' benutzen sollte; zum anderen worin sich 'hingehen' und 'dahingehen' denn unterscheiden. Sind sie doch normalerweise nicht austauschbar, zumindest insofern sie bedeuten, dass man an einen bestimmten Ort gehen möchte?
Sind z. B. die folgenden Sätze korrekt?

> A: Wollen wir mal ins Kino?
> B: Ja, ich möchte *hin / dahin*

(Es gibt zwar sicherlich auch Kontexte, in denen man nun 'hinwerfen' auswählen kann, aber ich möchte mich auf die Zusammenhänge beschränken, die mich durcheinanderbringen.)

Comment: Tja, was soll man dann von _**hin**ter**he**r_ halten?

Comment: Merke auch: Im Dialekt (Bayrisch) _Ja, gehs't glei her!_

Comment: Du verstehst das alles sehr gut. Mach jetzt nicht den Fehler, es kaputtzudenken. Jetzt: einfach sprechen, nicht zu viel grübeln!

Comment: Hinwerfen hat [mehrere Bedeutungen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hinwerfen). Bei "etwas hinwerfen" würde ich sofort an Bedeutung 3b denken. Und ja, die Verwendung von "werfen" ohne "hin"  oder "her" ist möglich und üblich und die Beispiele sind korrekt. "hingehen"  und "dahingehen" (nicht zu verwechseln mit "dahin gehen") haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen und jeweils auch mehrere Bedeutungen. Ich empfehle, auch hier bei duden.de nachzuschlagen.

Comment: Danke euch allen! @Roland ich meinte tatsächlich 'dahin gehen' : ich freue mich sehr über deine Anmerkung :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich gehe einzeln auf deine Fragen ein:

> In Bezug auf den ersten Fall würde ich sagen, dass - wenn die Richtung nicht angegeben wird - man etw. 'hinwirft'.

Stell dir unter 'hinwerfen' einfach 'loslassen' vor. Es fällt hin. Man hat schon das Bild vor Augen, dass die Dinge (der Schwerkraft folgend) in Richtung nach unten fallen - also einer Richtung folgend.

> Ist es doch denn wirklich so? Kann ich nur sagen 'Ich habe den Stein hin/her-geworfen' oder geht auch 'Ich habe den Stein (keine Richtungsangabe) geworfen'?

Es kommt immer darauf an, was du sagen willst. Willst du nur (ohne Verdeutlichung der Richtung) ausdrücken, dass der Stein irgendwie geflogen ist, kannst du einfach nur 'geworfen' verwenden. Willst du die Richtung betonen, verwendest du 'hinwerfen'/'herwerfen'. 'Ich habe den Stein geworfen'/'Er hat den Stein in den Teich geworfen' geht also auch, wenn die Richtung keine Rolle spielt.

> Was hingehen angeht, frage ich mich, zum einen, ob es auch hier gilt, dass man ohne Richtung 'hingehen' benutzen sollte;

'Hingehen' hat immer eine Richtung. Ein Ziel ist im Satz oder in den weiteren Sätzen dann irgendwie angegeben oder gemeint.

> zum anderen worin sich 'hingehen' und 'dahingehen' denn unterscheiden.

Die Zusammenschreibung mit 'gehen' ändert die Bedeutung. Hier bedeutet 'dahin' ein zeitliches Vorbei. Wenn etwas 'dahingeht', ist es gegangen oder sogar tot. Nicht zu verwechseln mit 'dahin gehen' (!), das ein Synonym ist für 'dort hingehen'/'dorthin gehen'/'da hingehen'/'hingehen' ist - also örtlich gemeint. Also: zusammen => zeitlich, auseinander => örtlich. Beim Sprechen legst du die Betonung auf auf 'da', wenn es örtlich gemeint ist, und auf 'hin', wenn es zeitlich gemeint ist.

> B: Ja, ich möchte hin / dahin

Beides ist richtig. Versteht man 'da' als 'dort', ist 'dahin' eine Verstärkung von 'hin' mit der zusätzlichen Angabe von 'da' als Zielort.

Comment: Siehe auch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18640/dahin-vs-da-hin

Comment: Vielen lieben Dank!

Comment: @Tristan, please accept the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm totally new here and I still don't know how everything works :)

Comment: @äüö "... 'Er hat den Stein in den Teich geworfen' geht also auch, wenn die Richtung keine Rolle spielt.": Ich finde, hier wird die Richtung schon durch "in den Teich" angegeben. "Er hat den Stein in den Teich hingeworfen" fände ich stlistisch ohne speziellen Kontext ziemlich fraglich.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: ja, das stimmt. In deinem Bsp. übernimmt "in den Teich" schon die Rolle des "hin". Ein sozusagen doppeltes "hin" wäre seltsam; man würde bei der Wortwahl dann wahrscheinlich erwarten, dass es jemand aus dem Teich wieder "her- bzw. zurück wirft".