# "dorthin gehen" vs. "dort hingehen"

Tags: meaning, spelling

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *dorthin gehen* und *dort hingehen* (oder *dahin gehen* und *da hingehen*)?

In welchen Situation werden die beiden Wortgruppen (nennt man das so?) verwendet? Könnt ihr Beispiele geben?

Comment: Related: [Hinkommen - Sprachgebrauch](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/18575/9551)

Comment: Servus und willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [Tour] der Seite nehmen. Fragen darüber, wie sie funktioniert, beantwortet dir das [Help].

Answer (score 2):

Beides ist sowohl möglich als auch richtig!

Es gibt allerdings einen kleinen Bedeutungsunterschied:

Wenn du *dorthin gehen* benutzt, dann **betonst du das gehen** und setzt es mit z.B. *fahren* oder *rennen* in Kontrast.

Die Benuztung von *dort hingehen* **klingt** (meiner Meinung nach) **natürlicher**. Das *dort* gibt den Ort an und das *hin* bezieht das *gehen* auf eben diesen Ort.

Kleiner Tipp am Rande: Ein weiteres Beispiel wäre vielleicht *dahin gehen* und *da hingehen*. Das darf natürlich auf keinen Fall mit *dahingehen* verglichen werden, was eine **völlig andere Bedeutung** hat.