# "hingehen", "dort hingehen", "dorthin gehen" — Which of those is more accurate and formal to say "I want to go there"?

Tags: difference, colloquial, formality

I have three statements to express "I want to go there." in German:

> 1. Ich will dort hingehen.
> 2. Ich will hingehen.
> 3. Ich will dorthin gehen.

Which one is more accurate and formal and which one is more colloquial?

Comment: The really informal one is: *Ich will da hin*.

Comment: Related: [“irgendwo hinfliegen” oder “irgendwohin fliegen”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/18536/9551), [“dorthin gehen” vs. “dort hingehen”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/32139/9551), and [Hinkommen - Sprachgebrauch](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/18575/9551)

Comment: Also related: [“dahin” vs. “da hin”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/18640/1224)

Comment: Ok, so can we conclude that "da hin" is more informal than "dort hin"?

Comment: @Armin Don't get distracted by "da" vs "dort". That's a different question.

Comment: Without context it is hard to say whether the *da* should be implicit or explicit.

Comment: @CarstenS , So could you please give us examples to understand each one of these three using context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three are possible with slightly different emphasis.

> Ich will dort hingehen.

Here you emphasize the place where you want to go to. (Think of pointing at a map, saying "dort...". But of course this can be used in other situations as well.)

> Ich will dorthin gehen.

Here you emphasize that you want to walk there (and not *fahren/fliegen/....*).

> Ich will hingehen.

This would typically be used with some event and emphasizes that you want to take part in that event. For example: *Warst du schon beim Konzert von Rammstein? Noch nicht, aber ich will hingehen." This construction is similar to *Ich will da hin.* (which is less formal).